# Cascaded delete is not working in EF 6 Code First

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following entities

```
public class Division
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SubDivision SubDivision { get; set; }
}

public class SubDivision
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then fluent API

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Division>()
                        .HasOptional(x => x.SubDivision)
                        .WithOptionalDependent()
                        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Then I try to delete a Division and I am expecting its SubDivisions to be deleted by the don't

```
Division div = c.Divisions.Include(x => x.SubDivision).First();
c.Divisions.Remove(div);
c.SaveChanges();
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cascade delete works always from *principal* (the entity being referenced) to *dependent* (the entity referencing it), i.e. deleting the principal automatically deletes the dependent(s).

In one-to-many relationship the principal is always the one side and dependent - the many side.

In one-to-one relationship the required end is always the principal and the optional end - dependent. However if both ends are required or both ends are optional (as yours), the principal and dependent are determined by the configuration. In your case, the `.WithOptionalDependent()` line is telling EF that the entity being configured (`Division`) is the *dependent*, hence `Division` will have a FK to `SubDivision` and deleting the `SubDivision` will also delete the `Division`.

If the intent was different (as it seems by the question), simply replace

```
.WithOptionalDependent()
```

with

```
.WithOptionalPrincipal()
```